# how to make uitextview none scrollable but display all content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

At the moment in my IB I have a View Controller which is covered by a UIScroll View. Within the scroll view I have a UIImageView at the top, a UILableView in the middile and a MKMapView at the bottom. The UILableView number of lines is set to 0 (infinite) and word wrap allowing me display as much content as I want.

I want to be able to tap telephone numbers and website url's for the content in my UILableView. The best way I've found so far is to change it to a UITextView which handles all of this for you. However... I can not get the same behaviour with the scrolling.

Before the image, label and map used to scroll as a block. Now, only the textView scrolls. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

the displaying part is correct, that is calculate the frame of the textView based on the size of its text for scrolling add this `[textView setScrollEnabled:NO];`

Comment: This does not work. It cuts the text off to how big its frame is in the IB.

Comment: oh.. i am sorry i thought u took care of the frame part.. please add the below code..  
 
    `CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(maxWidthOfTextview, 9999);
     UIFont *myFont = textView.font;
     CGSize myStringSize = [textView.text sizeWithFont:myFont constrainedToSize:maximumSize    lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
     textView.frame = CGRectMake (textView.frame.origin.x, textView.frame.origin.y, myStringSize.width, myStringSize.height)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this project:

https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel

```
label.dataDetectorTypes = NSTextCheckingTypeLink; // Automatically detect links when the label text is subsequently changed
label.delegate = self; // Delegate methods are called when the user taps on a link (see `TTTAttributedLabelDelegate` protocol)

label.text = @"Fork me on GitHub! (http://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/)"; // Repository URL will be automatically detected and linked

NSRange range = [label.text rangeOfString:@"me"];
[label addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://github.com/mattt/"] withRange:range]; // Embedding a custom link in a substring
```

Comment: A good work around, however I didn't want to add more wheels to the project. There must be a way around this in the IB.